# Filtering AD Group by User Properties ; Returning improperly

Tags: powershell

Disclaimer: I am not good with powershell, this in mainly butchered code. I apologize if this is done poorly or is a stupid question.

I am trying to filter the ACTIVE users in my company by their company (ET) and whether or not they are in a certain group.

So the filter for ACTIVE users in the company "ET" is working properly, the output of this script gives me every active users with that parameter; it does not filter it further down into only users in a certain group.

```
$users = Get-ADUser -filter {(Enabled -eq $True) -and (Company -eq "ET")}  
-SearchBase 'DC=CSOKI,DC=Local' |select -exp samaccountname
$group = "O365-E3-Full"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select - 
ExpandProperty samaccountname
ForEach ($user in $users) {
If ($members -contains $user) {
  Write-output  $(name) | out-file ".\TEST.txt"
 } Else {
  Write-Host "$user does not exist in the group"
}}
```

Expected:
Output ACTIVE users in company ET that are in group O365-E3-FULL and write-host users that are not(unnecessary, I just want the filter).

Actual:
Write-hosts every ACTIVE user in company ET and ignores the group filter.

Comment: does `$users` contain the EXACT SAME NAME as the equivalent name in `$members`? the `-contains` collection operator requires an exact match ... you use `.Name` for one collection and `.SamAccountName` for the other.

Comment: That fixed a portion of it! Such a silly mistake;

Now it outputs correctly but throws an error saying that "The term 'name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" referencing the write-output section.

What would be the correct format for that? I other methods but they only output the last user rather than compiling them.

Comment: this `Write-output  $(name)` doesn't make any sense. [*grin*] what is `name` in that context? it aint a variable ...

Comment: Haha! It definitely doesn't! I honestly just left it because nothing else was working. I'm basically trying to get it to compile and output all users that match the parameters. Using Write-output $user just overwrites it instead of compiling it.

Comment: i saw your "only shows the last one" comment. that is caused by writing to the file INSIDE your loop. if you want to do it that way, add `-Append` to the `Out-File` cmdlet parameters. [*grin*]

Comment: You're amazing, thanks so much for the assistance with that! It's working like a charm now.

Hope you have a great weekend!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

In getting your list of users you are collecting the **account name** for the users with:

```
| Select -exp samaccountname
```

Then in getting group members you are getting the **Name** with:

```
| Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

You need to be selecting SamAccountName in both of your Gets

Comment: That was exactly the issue, I edited my original post to reflect what is now working mostly properly.

Now it outputs correctly but throws an error saying that "The term 'name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" referencing the write-output section. What would be the correct format for that? I  tried other methods but they only output the last user rather than compiling all of them.

Comment: This line:
Write-output  $(name) | out-file ".\TEST.txt" the $(name) is the issue.  Do you want $user to the text file

Comment: I do, but whenever I try Write-output $user | out-file ".\TEST.txt" it will only output the last user that it processed rather than compiling each user that fit the parameters.

There are 6 total users that fit the parameters and it outputs the same(last) user each time.

Comment: Yep, I've searched around trying to find an alternative that would compile it rather than overwrite but I can't find anything.

Comment: Yea, I think that additional answer will solve that.  Put the correct users in to  new array and then output the whole array after the loop

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, pretty quick knock together

```
# Create empty array
$answer = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

# If is in group then add to array
If ($members -contains $user) {
  $answer.Add($user) > $null
} Else {
  Write-Host $user "does not exist in the group"
}

# Output the array to the text file
Write-output  $answer | out-file ".\TEST.txt"
```

Comment: Lee_Dailey provided the -append solution and it worked like a charm, thanks so much for your earlier help man. Hope your weekend goes great as well! Cheers.